# How to display the first 3 li with 100% and per row 2 li with 33.33% width?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, html-lists

I have a design with me. I am getting one issue here.

[image]

What I a doing is, I have to display first 3 li tag with 100% width and remain li tag with 33.33%.

**This is my expected output**

```
li-100% width
li-100% width
li-100% width
li-33.33% width | li-33.33% width | big image here(not a part of loop)
li-33.33% width | li-33.33% width |
li-33.33% width | li-33.33% width |
```

But notice here, I am using `while` loop so I will get output like

```
li-100% width
li-100% width
li-100% width
li-33.33% width | li-33.33% width | li-33.33% width
li-33.33% width | li-33.33% width | li-33.33% width
li-33.33% width | li-33.33% width | li-33.33% width
```

I have to display only 2 li per row.

**I am using below logic**

```
<div class="wrapperClass">
  <ul>
    <?php
      $index = 0;
      $check=0;
       while ( condition ) {
         if ($index < 3) {?>
      <li>
        <!--width 100%-->
      </li>
      <?php }
                else{?>
      <li>
        <!--width with 33.33-->
      </li>
      <?php } $index++;}?>
  </ul>
  <img src="">
</div>
```

**css**

```
.wrapperClass ul li:nth-child(1),.wrapperClass ul li:nth-child(2),.wrapperClass ul li:nth-child(3){
    width:100%;
}
.wrapperClass ul li{width:33.33%;display: inline-block;}
```

Would you help me out with this issue?

Comment: when you create li, you can give different class and use css in suitable class

Comment: Please provide output html or fiddle link

Comment: @chandershekhar fiddle link will not work here because of logic. and I shared my expected output in the above image.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra, Can you share one example?

Comment: @NarenVerma provide output html

Comment: @chandershekhar: this is my output <ul>
 <li><!-- div--></li>
 <li><!-- div--></li>
 <li><!-- div--></li>
 <li><!-- div--></li>
 <li><!-- div--></li>
 <li><!-- div--></li>
 <li><!-- div--></li>
 <li><!-- div--></li>
 <li><!-- div--></li>
</ul>

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. This code is only for reference.

```js
      
      var html = '';
      for(var i = 1; i<= 9; i++){
      
        if(i <= 3){
          html += "<li class='fullli'> full </li> ";
          
        }else {
           html += "<li class='halflli'> half </li> ";
        }
      }
      
      $('.mainul').html(html);
```

```css
.fullli {
  width : 100%;
}
.halflli {
  width : 33%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapperClass">
  <ul class="mainul">
   
  </ul>
  <img src="">
</div>
```

Comment: @Devshi, Give me some time to check

Comment: I tried your code but I am not getting my expect output. this is the output I am getting https://prnt.sc/q0flhl   I have to display only 2 li in row instated of 3

Answer (score 0):

Use this css

```css
.wrapperClass ul li:nth-child(-n+3){
    width:100%;
}
.wrapperClass ul li{display: inline-block; width:33.33%;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapperClass">
  <ul>
    <li>Some text</li>
    <li>Some text</li>
    <li>Some text</li>
    <li>Some text</li>
    <li>Some text</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not my expected output.

Comment: I tried your code but I am not getting my expect output. this is the output I am getting prnt.sc/q0flhl I have to display only 2 li in row instated of 3 afte displaying the 3 li with 100%

Comment: @NarenVerma, perhaps, you have an upper-level css which affects on provided answers. That's why you'll never find an answer here even if they're working well.

Comment: @AksenP, I am also trying but I am confused about what logic I have to use after the 3 li. I can change the CSS according to the output.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this using a grid layout. Here is an example:

`HTML`

```
<div class="layout">
  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
    <li>five</li>
    <li>six</li>
    <li>seven</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="some-image.png" alt="some image">
  </div>
</div>
```

`CSS`

```
.layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
}

ul {
  display: contents;
  list-style: none;
}

li:nth-child(-n + 3) {
  background-color: #bada55;
  grid-column: 1/4;
}

li:nth-child(2n + 4) {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

li:nth-child(2n + 5) {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.image-wrapper {
  background-color: hotpink;
  grid-column: 3/4;
  grid-row: 4/7;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  /*just some random height to demonstrate
  that the items on the left side will keep their height
  even with a much higher image on the right side.
  I would recomment setting the height to 'auto' though.*/
  height: 250px;
}
```

Be aware that the css techniques I use here are not supported by Internet Explorer 11 for the most part since this browser uses an older specification of the grid. You may have to find a workaround for Internet Explorer 11 if you want to support it as well.

If you can change the structure of your HTML you can also do something like this:

`HTML`

```
<div class="container">
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
  <div>three</div>
  <div class="columns">
    <div>
        <div>four</div>
        <div>five</div>
        <div>six</div>
        <div>seven</div>
        <div>eight</div>
        <div>nine</div>
        <div>ten</div>
        <div>eleven</div>
        <div>...and so on</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="some-image.png" alt="some image">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`CSS`

```
.columns {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.columns > *:first-child {
  width: 66%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.columns > *:first-child > * {
  width: 50%;
}

.columns > *:last-child {
  width: 34%;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: any other solution without grid ?

Comment: You could change the structure of your html. Then it would be easy to build this using flex-box or even float.

Comment: change the structure means? Should I need to change the design?

Comment: In your second solution, If I get more then 6 record the it will not work like my expected output... I am getting the records from the database

Comment: Yes I checked updated answer but dynamically it's not working.

Comment: Please describe the issue more presicely as the code is clearly working.

Comment: I am getting data from the database. I want to know how can I add <div class="columns"><div> when loop is working.

Comment: You can simply put the loop inside the columns container and just create your items inside the loop. Basically the same way as you have done in your question. `<div class="columns"><div>...php loop goes here....</div></div>`